# SQL Server / T-SQL: Return a single value from a constructed table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am writing an inline function, which accepts a fixed number of parameters (9 in the code example), arranges those parameters into a constructed table with 2 columns and 4 rows, sorts the table, and then returns a single value from said table (the value in column 1, and in whichever row 1-4 the calling statement requested).

I've got most of it done.

But I need to know how to select a specific column and row index at the end.

You may be asking why I need an inline function for this, and the answer is because a) the sorting is crucial and b) this is being used in a computed column in a memory-optimized table, where sub-queries are not allowed, etc.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SelectOrderedInputValue]
(
    -- 1-based row index of the desired return value
    @RequestedRowIndex INT,

    @InputValue1 INT,
    @InputValue2 INT,
    @InputValue3 INT,
    @InputValue4 INT,
    @InputRank1 INT,
    @InputRank2 INT,
    @InputRank3 INT,
    @InputRank4 INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    /* Places the parameters into a table, and sorts by rank.

       I need to figure out how to specify a row and column,
       so I can return the single requested value from this table.

       In this case, I need to return the value in column #1 (alias InputValues)
       and row # @RequestedRowIndex*/

    SELECT TOP 4 InputValues FROM
    (VALUES
        ([InputValue1], [InputRank1]),
        ([InputValue2], [InputRank2]),
        ([InputValue3], [InputRank3]),
        ([InputValue4], [InputRank4])
    ) AS Inputs(InputValues, InputRanks) ORDER BY InputRanks ASC
)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: T-SQL does not work with column numbers. It *can* work with row numbers (through the aptly named `ROW_NUMBER()`) but any "column number" has to be handled explicitly with a `CASE` (or maybe an `UNPIVOT` -- the essence is that both require specifying the column by name).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good to know! In this case, specifying the column by name is fine. I'll google ROW_NUMBER now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to return a table for a single value.  Just use a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SelectOrderedInputValue] (
    -- 1-based row index of the desired return value
    @RequestedRowIndex INT,

    @InputValue1 INT,
    @InputValue2 INT,
    @InputValue3 INT,
    @InputValue4 INT,
    @InputRank1 INT,
    @InputRank2 INT,
    @InputRank3 INT,
    @InputRank4 INT
) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    /* Places the parameters into a table, and sorts by rank.

       I need to figure out how to specify a row and column,
       so I can return the single requested value from this table.

       In this case, I need to return the value in column #1 (alias InputValues)
       and row # @RequestedRowIndex*/
    DECLARE @retval INT;

    SET @retval = (SELECT TOP 4 *
                   FROM (VALUES ([InputValue1], [InputRank1]),
                                ([InputValue2], [InputRank2]),
                                ([InputValue3], [InputRank3]),
                                ([InputValue4], [InputRank4])
                        ) Inputs(InputValues, InputRanks)
                   ORDER BY InputRanks ASC
                   OFFSET @RequestedRowIndex-1 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
                  );

    RETURN @retval;
END;
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps if the scalar function was natively complied. An inline function seemed a bit more streamlined for the in-memory OLTP stuff I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [OFFSET FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
    DECLARE @RequestedRowIndex INT=4
    SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT TOP 4 * FROM
    (VALUES
        (10, 11),
        (20, 21),
        (30, 31),
        (40, 41)
    ) AS Inputs(InputValues, InputRanks) 
    ORDER BY InputRanks ASC )A 
    ORDER BY InputRanks ASC  
    OFFSET @RequestedRowIndex-1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Interesting, lemme try this out real quick.

Comment: as commenters said, I am filtering rows, not columns or I may misunderstood your question..

Comment: You understood correctly. Filtering rows is what I need.

Comment: OFFSET for one record? row_number() + WHERE r_n = @RequestedRowIndex